# Alter Table Add Column Syntax

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ddl

I'm trying to programmatically add an identity column to a table Employees. Not sure what I'm doing wrong with my syntax.

```
ALTER TABLE Employees
  ADD COLUMN EmployeeID int NOT NULL IDENTITY (1, 1)

ALTER TABLE Employees ADD CONSTRAINT
    PK_Employees PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
      EmployeeID
    ) WITH( STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, 
    ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
```

What am I doing wrong? I tried to export the script, but SQL Mgmt Studio does a whole Temp Table rename thing.

**UPDATE**:
I think it is choking on the first statement with "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'COLUMN'."

Answer (score 207, accepted):

Just remove `COLUMN` from `ADD COLUMN`

```
ALTER TABLE Employees
  ADD EmployeeID numeric NOT NULL IDENTITY (1, 1)

ALTER TABLE Employees ADD CONSTRAINT
        PK_Employees PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
        (
          EmployeeID
        ) WITH( STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, 
        ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Comment: To clarify, the 'COLUMN' keyword is only valid (but not required) in MySQL.

Comment: @ethanbustad It is also valid for DB2 and Postgres.

Comment: Ridiculous that they don't just ignore the `column` keyword and make it work like every other DB out there.

Comment: FYI, Oracle behaves in the same way as SQL Server in this case - both don't allow `COLUMN` in the `ADD` statement.

Answer (score 17):

This is how Adding new column to Table

```
ALTER TABLE [tableName]
ADD ColumnName Datatype
```

**E.g**

```
ALTER TABLE [Emp]
ADD Sr_No Int
```

And If you want to make it auto incremented

```
ALTER TABLE [Emp]
ADD Sr_No Int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 8):

The correct syntax for adding column into table is:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
  ADD column_name column-definition;
```

In your case it will be:

```
ALTER TABLE Employees
  ADD EmployeeID int NOT NULL IDENTITY (1, 1)
```

To add multiple columns use brackets:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
  ADD (column_1 column-definition,
       column_2 column-definition,
       ...
       column_n column_definition);
```

`COLUMN` keyword in SQL SERVER is used only for altering:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
  ALTER COLUMN column_name column_type;
```

Comment: Thanks for mentioning multiple columns.

Answer (score 0):

It could be doing the temp table renaming if you are trying to add a column to the beginning of the table (as this is easier than altering the order). Also, if there is data in the Employees table, it has to do insert select * so it can calculate the EmployeeID.

Comment: "easier that altering the order" - Do you mean that it is possible (although it is more difficult) to alter the order of the columns without recreating the table (through a temp table)?

Comment: In a relational database, you should never have a need for the ordinality of the columns so if you are trying to neatly order the columns, the question is why? If column ordinality was so important, why isn't there a trivial function to swap or fix ordinality of columns? The reason is it designed for ordinality to not matter.